# How to find the number of (key , value) pairs in a map in scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, scala-collections

I need to find the number of (key , value) pairs in a Map in my Scala code. I can iterate through the map and get an answer but I wanted to know if there is any direct function for this purpose or not.

Comment: You might find it helpful to spend some time looking at the [Scala Collections API](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html) document and trying things out in the REPL. Having a working knowledge of what you can do with collections will help you tackle a lot of problems.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you can use [`.size`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map@size:Int)

```
scala> val m=Map("a"->1,"b"->2,"c"->3)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)

scala> m.size
res3: Int = 3
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Map#size`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map@size:Int):

> The size of this traversable or iterator.

The `size` method is from TraversableOnce so, barring infinite sequences or sequences that shouldn't be iterated again, it can be used over a wide range - List, Map, Set, etc.