# Count number of key in list of Map in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a list of Map:

`List(Map(148e0b9b-e142-493f-a298-27e0ebd453bc -> 12, 15ddf513-44aa-4285-82cb-31017da99a64 -> 18, ce760bd7-0c2c-4f0f-9303-1ba77346694c -> 3))`.

Here, every list contains only one map. I want to **count** how many key-value pair are there in the list of Map. Though it can be done by iterating and incrementing counter, but I am looking for something like one-liner.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952447/how-to-find-the-number-of-key-value-pairs-in-a-map-in-scala) is bit closer to my question, but I don't know how to unpack map from list of Map.

Expected output: 3.

Comment: If you know the list has only one map, why don't you get the list's head?

Comment: Oh! so cool. I didn't had idea. I am noob in scala. I would have saved my one hour, if I had posted one hour before. @CyrilleCorpet, thanks a ton :)

Comment: `list.head.size` works like charm. :)

Comment: May I know the reason from dear down-voter, why you down-voted my question?

Comment: ^ Hi Om. It's fine to enquire about voting decisions in the comments if you wish, though I personally think it's a waste of time. However, please don't edit voting advice or commentary into posts - most readers don't sign in or vote, so it is not of interest to them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Version, which works, and also works for a list with multiple maps:

```
list.map{x => x.size}.sum
```

It gets the number of map-elements for each list-element, and sums up the result.